# how to match lines without some strings in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I tried to print out the first line (started with > as the files are fasta files) of every file under the folder and use sed to extract out those lines without plasmid and fragment.

I did `ls * | xargs -I one sed -n -e '/^>.*[^fragment|plasmid].*/p' one > outfile`
but it dosen't work? How should I modify it?

Comment: Square brackets are never the right grouping operator for regular expressions.  `[a|bc]` matches a single character which is one of `a`, `|`, `b`, or `c`.  In some regex dialects, `(a|bc)` matches either `a` or `bc`, and some dialects want that as `\(a\|bc\)`.  But you cannot use negation inside the regex, except in Perl-compatible regular expressions, like `>(?!.*(?:fragment|plasmid)).*$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
head -q -n 1 * | egrep -v "^>.*(fragment|plasmid).*"
```

Comment: actually your previous answer before edit works as well, not sure why you modified it. Still wondering if sed can manage the job.

Comment: @lolibility Why do you care if sed can be made to do it? sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for any other text manipulation you should just use awk. Most of seds language constructs became obsolete when awk was invented in the mid-1970s.

Answer (score 2):

Am I right in thinking you just want to print the first line from every file if that line does not contain fragment or plasmid? That'd just be:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && !/fragment|plasmid/' *
```

If that's not what you want, update your question with some representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: You should exit after the first line, otherwise you're looping over the rest of the lines for no reason.

Comment: Just like in the posted sed solutions, right? If I add an exit after the first line then the script will only process 1 file. In GNU awk you can use nextfile but then it's gawk-specific. You could call awk one file at time in a loop or via xargs and then use the exit you suggested but then you're adding the loop and process overhead so that'd probably be slower than today. In reality just using the script as-is will almost certainly be absolutely fine and if the OP finds it does need to be sped up then we can talk about the pros/cons of various solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your requirement as print lines beginning with > unless they contain fragment or plasmid, then I think this will do it for you:

```
sed -ne '/^>/{/fragment/;b;/plasmid/b;p;}' one > outfile
```

It ignores all lines that don't begin with >, and if it finds fragment or plasmid it skips to the end of the script and goes to the next line.